# How to pass TouchUpInside event to a UIButton, without passing it to parent views?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, gesture-recognition

I have a UIScrollview with paging enabled. There are 3 views (pages) inside this scroll view. There's a tap gesture on the parent view of the scrollview that shows and hides a navigation bar at the top.

**The Problem:**
In one of the pages I want to add buttons. But the problem is that whenever i tap these buttons, the show/hide navigation bar method is also fired. What is the best way to pass the touch only to these buttons and not the the parent view of the scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NJones is on the right track, but I think there are some problems with his answer.

I assume that you want to pass through touches on *any* button in your scroll view.  In your gesture recognizer's delegate, implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` like this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    UIView *gestureView = recognizer.view;
    // gestureView is the view that the recognizer is attached to - should be the scroll view

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:gestureView];
    UIView *touchedView = [gestureView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
    // touchedView is the deepest descendant of gestureView that contains point

    // Block the recognizer if touchedView is a UIButton, or a descendant of a UIButton
    while (touchedView && touchedView != gestureView) {
        if ([touchedView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            return NO;
        touchedView = touchedView.superview;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I missed how he said buttons plural. Tisk tisk. My answer was copied from one of my other answers where the was one view to exclude. This is much better for multiples.

Comment: I am going to try this out right now. Strangely, I did not get a notification from Stackoverflow about this. But this does look like a solid solution. Thanks for replying guys!